# PWM timer 2 software implementation on AVR atmega16

Tags: c, avr

I'm implementing PWM on ATmega16 in order to be able to control 20 concurrent servos. I've successfully implemented 16 servos on timer 1, while timer 2 has problems, changing the values of output angles during runtime. i.e. when using pre-initialized angles for Timer 2, PWM signals are correct, while changing the angle values in real time causes modified angle values NOT to be output (no signal is output)

```
ISR(TIMER2_OVF_vect) {
TCNT2 = 0xFF - (SERVO_TIME*(F_CPU/1000000))/256 - truncf(50/8); // set max duty cycle , 50 added to sum up the 20 ms period
servo_index_2++;
if (servo_index_2 > 7)
    servo_index_2 = 0;
OCR2 = TCNT2 + angles0[servo_index_2]; 
PORTC |= 1 << servo_index_2 ;
}
```

why ISR is not setting angles on runtime

Comment: Your `TIMER2_OVF_vect` looks like you tried to write it two different ways and left both of them in the code. Why are you incrementing `servo_index_2` twice and setting `OCR2` twice?

Comment: thank you, fixed this one but still I have the same problem, I edited the post with the new code, please take a look

Comment: should the code between `index_2++` and writing to `PORTC` not run in some kind of loop to set the bit for each PWM channel during the same ISR call? Here at each call to the ISR routine you will set `angles0` for the "next" port; and is `angles0[]` defined so that the ISR routine can access it when its values are modified "outside"?

Comment: the entire idea of this is to serve a PWN channel, move on to the next channel till the 7th channel, then returning to index 0 for example. OVF_ISR sets the pin to 1, while COMP ISR sets it back to 0 when OCR2 hits a compare match

Comment: What are the values of the Waveform Generation mode (WGM21:0) and Compare Output mode (COM21:0) bits?